# What's the difference between just using multiple froms and joins?

Tags: sql, join

Say I have this query:

```
SELECT bugs.id, bug_color.name FROM bugs, bug_color
    WHERE bugs.id = 1 AND bugs.id = bug_color.id
```

Why would I use a join? And what would it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joins are synticatic sugar, easier to read.

Your query would look like this with a join:

```
SELECT bugs.id, bug_color.name 
FROM bugs
INNER JOIN bug_color ON bugs.id = bug_color.id
WHERE bugs.id = 1
```

With more then two tables, joins help make a query more readable, by keeping conditions related to a table in one place.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that "syntactic sugar" is the right phrase. The "JOIN" keyword has semantic meaning -- whether the db engine chooses to act upon it is immaterial.

Comment: I believe what Andomar means by "syntactic sugar" is that for inner joins, the two forms (old-style and ANSI JOIN using INNER JOIN) are equivalent. Still, for outer joins the styles are very different, so I can't quite agree with it being syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

The `join` keyword is the new way of joining tables.

When I learned SQL it did not yet exist, so joining was done the way that you show in your question.

Nowadays we have things like joins and aliases to make the queries more readable:

```
select
    b.id, c.name
from
    bugs as b
inner join
    bug_color as c on c.id = b.id
where
    b.id = 1
```

Also there are other variations of joins, as `left outer join`, `right outer join` and `full join`, that is harder to accomplish with the old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Join syntax allows for outer joins, so you can go:

```
SELECT bugs.id, bug_color.name 
FROM bugs, bug_color 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bug_color ON bugs.id = bug_color.id
WHERE bugs.id = 1
```

Comment: In Oracle you can have outer joins with the from syntax.  It uses the (+) modifier, like "where bugs.id = bug_color.id(+)"

Comment: you can perform OUTER JOINS without join syntax, using *= or =* in the appropriate WHERE clause

Comment: *= is not normally supported in SQL Server or in ANSI SQL.